# Published Monogame Project doesn't run

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm working on a video game made ith MonoGame and I need some help.

When I'm running the game with VS2013, everything it fine ! But when I publish the project and I'm running it : instant crash.

I'm launching debug with VS and this error is concerning the loading of "font.xnb". But I've attached to the file "font.xnb" the property copy always and made it come from my bin project folder (as said on the tutorial from internet).

How can we then explain why game is running on VS but not after it has been published ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting the 'Copy to Output Directory' appropriately, have you also set the 'Build Action' to 'Content' (or something else appropriate)?

Publishing usually only picks up certain types of content and it sounds like your publishing step isn't including that file. The 'Copy to Output Directory' is more likely to affect the Visual Studio build than it is the publishing step.

Comment: It's work ! XNB Files are not auto-set to 'Content' in 'Build Action' ... I'm a dumb sorry x)


Thank you for your help ScheuNZ :D